# How do you troubleshoot the blank (white or black) screen in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

While writing my Ionic application, I made some change to my application and then viewed the result in Chrome Canary (after getting the app running using the `ionic serve` command).

All that I see is a black screen. (In some other similar cases, I've seen simply a white screen.)

There is no output on the console of the browser and no output in the terminal window.

It would be desirable to have some sort of parser error or - anything - to assist in finding the root cause.

In other words - I don't want to troubleshoot my specific error right now, I want to learn how to troubleshoot this on my own. What are some good next steps to follow?

Comment: You mentioned you see nothing in Console, but what about the Network tab - any errors there?

Comment: Network tab shows no errors, all 200's and 304's.

Comment: When you run ionic at the command line, does it warn you about an updated version? If you run the www folder via a regular web server, do things show up?

Comment: There is no warning about version. I can view some other pages in the app, so it seems that the server is functioning properly. I believe it has to do with state changes in the ui-router. I have found this related post and will try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745761/what-is-the-angular-ui-router-lifecycle-for-debugging-silent-errors