# When has ng-switch finished rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-switch

I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and trying to instantiate a widget that takes as a parameter a DOM element specified by id. This DOM element is in a `<div ng-switch>` and I want to call the widget constructor when the element is guaranteed to exist.

```
<div ng-switch on="state">
  <div ng-switch-when="map">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the [ui-router lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745761/what-is-the-angular-ui-router-lifecycle-for-debugging-silent-errors), I understand that I should hook into `$viewContentLoaded`. This, however, doesn't work - the DOM element within the `ng-switch` isn't created at that point:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('/', {url: '/', templateUrl: 'index.html'})
    .state('map', {url: 'map', templateUrl: 'map.html', controller: 'MapCtrl'})
}]);

app.controller('MapCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', function MapCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $state) {
  $scope.state = $state.current.name;  // expose the state to the template so we can ng-switch. Apparently there's no better way: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1482

  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function mapContentLoaded(event, viewConfig) {
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    console.log('Attempting to create map into', mapElement);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement);  // <-- but mapElement will be null!
  });
}]);
```

What does work is using a `setTimeout()` of 50ms in the controller, which is brittle, but by that time the DOM element is created. Alternatively, I can set an interval, check for the presence of the `map` DOM element, and clear the interval when it's found.

What is the *proper* way of figuring out when an `ng-switch` has rendered its DOM? This [isn't documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

**Here's the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NbSZYV?p=info)**.

Comment: you are mixing metaphors/domains by using dom methods and angular methods together, which doesn't work very well with angular. use directives or templates to manipulate mapElement instead of dom methods.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the `mapElement`? Whatever it may be, @dandavis is correct you usually only want to do DOM manipulation in directives.

Comment: @EstebanFelix: I want to instantiate a Google Map. Just updated the question. How should I go about it? Use ui-router states instead of ng-switch?

Comment: luckily, there are lots of google map components ready to go for angular, search around for one

Comment: @dandavis: I know. The two most popular ones depend on jQuery for no reason, which isn't acceptable for my client. I've already filed GitHub issues for that, e.g. [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/801).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Check out my answer and you can see how to do it "the Angular way"

Answer (score 1):

I think you're falling in the trap that many experienced front-end developers fall in to when using Angular. In most of other JS libraries we modify the DOM after it's been created and then add functionality to it. However, in Angular the functionality is defined in the HTML. Functionality and interactivity is created by using directives.

**In jQuery** something like this is fine:

```
<div id="foobar">
    Click here to do stuff
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#foobar').on('click', function () {
            someService.doStuff();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Whereas **in Angular** something like the below is more idiomatic:

```
<div id="foobar" ng-controller="Main" ng-click="doStuff()">
    Click here to do stuff
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    app.controller('Main', ['$scope', 'somerService', function ($scope, someService) {
        $scope.doStuff = function () {
            someService.doStuff();
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

As for your GoogleMap directive this is by far the simplest way to accomplish it. Albeit this is incredibly basic and may not do everything you need it to.

```
app.directive('googleMap', [function() {
    return {
      link: function(element) {
        new google.maps.Map(element);
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

*Your `map.html`:*

```
<div ng-switch on="state">
  <div ng-switch-when="map">
    <div google-map id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you mentioned however, this would recreate the Google map every time that controller is hit. One way around that is to save off the element and Map api and replacing it on subsequent calls:

```
app.directive('googleMap', [function () {
    var googleMapElement,
            googleMapAPI;
    return {
        link: function (element) {
            if (!googleMapElement || !googleMapAPI) {
                googleMapAPI = new google.maps.Map(element);
                googleMapElement = element;
            }
            else {
                element.replaceWith(googleMapElement);
            }

        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Gotta read the [jQuery -> Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) SO one more time. Will using a directive cause the map to be re-created every time the router lands on that page? That's something I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I would be a liar if I said I hadn't read that before writing this response. It's definitely a muscle you need to relearn if you've done jQuery for a long time. Unfortunately it will recreate it every time the switch is activated.

Comment: I managed to avoid the re-creation, it seems, by storing `mapDomElement = document.getElementById('map')` into a `map.domElements` `.value` after running `new google.maps.Map(...)`, then running `mapDomElement.parentNode.replaceChild(map.domElements, mapDomElement);` if that value was set, instead of calling the Google Maps constructor.

Comment: Alas, it seems that [ng-switch isn't the way to go when using ui-router](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/22/the-basics-of-using-ui-router-with-angularjs/). Rather, one should use nested states and views.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Ahh you beat me to the punch =P. Yeah, long-term it definitely seems like that is a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks again for helping tackle this! The directive code *should* work, but in practice I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined` at some VM:xxxx point in the Google Maps minified code. The API and the Element are correct; no idea what ends up happening.