# viewContentLoaded event called multiple times for a single TemplateURL ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a view as

```
 <div class="wrapper" ui-view>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

And the state that renderes a template called `_BodyLayout` is

```
(function () {
    angular.module('ngApp').config(configuration);

    configuration.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function configuration($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: '/Shared/_Bodylayout',
        });
    }

})(angular);
```

I have a run method where the template should register all plugins exactly once for the template when rendered as :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("ngApp").run(run);

    run.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'plugin-factory', '$timeout'];

    function run($rootScope, plugins, $timeout) {

        $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
             plugins.run();
        });
    }

})(angular);
```

But on console.log shows that this event runs for multiple times and the `plugins.run()` method has been called at least 5 times for a single `templateURL` !!! That makes my sidebar plugin behave weird .

Can anyone tell me why its running 5 times instead of one time for a single templateURL ?

[image]

Comment: do you have 5+ ui-view attred tags too?

Comment: @YOU nope . I have only one . The one which I have given above . But in the child BodyLayout I do have but they are all named

Comment: as far as I know, each ui-view attr trigger $viewContentLoaded event.

Comment: Ok so in the sense for all ui-view="somename" also being targetted by the state mentioned above ?

Comment: I am not sure about named ui-view, but normal ui-view and nested ui-view does, but I think its just a name.

Comment: well yes I guess thats the case . I removed all named `ui-view` from attrs and the the `$viewContentLoaded` came down to two . But still its two but not one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76243/discussion-between-joy-and-you).

Comment: I have no idea why it is two. do you have abstract?

Comment: Nope No abstract is there . Now only a Layout into which I have ui-view ... and inside the layout I am rendering bodylayout . But bodylayout doesn't have any sort of ui-view anymore

Comment: I see, strange indeed.

Comment: I have removed all occurances of ui-view except for the root ui-view which is unnamed . Still the count is two

Comment: may be you can debug, some of its event like in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745761/what-is-the-angular-ui-router-lifecycle-for-debugging-silent-errors