# AngularJS ignore routing by ui.route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try change build-in Angular route mechanism to ui.router. So I included angular.ui.router.js to my index.html and to my module:

```
var app = angular.module('multibookWeb', ['ui.router']);
```

Next I set routing in app.config:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');
    $stateProvider
        .state('list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: '/partials/list/list.html',
        });
```

Console don't show any errors, but routing doesn't work. I fired www.someAddress.com/# and I expect that my routing redirects me to www.someAddress.com/#/list or something like this. Unfortunately it doesn't happend. When I console (inside $watch) value of $state.current.name it return me empty string. I tried debugging by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745761/what-is-the-angular-ui-router-lifecycle-for-debugging-silent-errors/20786262#20786262), but console is still empty...

My Angular version: 1.2.28

My Ui.router version: 0.2.13

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EygPe7dkS88sY6LEzRYZ) is plunker

Comment: Could you provide a plnkr?

Comment: Sure, I added link to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you have no `ui-view`.

For the ui-router to function you will need an `ui-view`. Replace your `ng-view` with `ui-view` and it will work.