# UI Router parameter URL not working just redirecting to /

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am trying to get UI router to have a detailed message view, here is the code:

```
  .state('app.messages.detail', {
        url: 'messages/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'templates/views/message.html',
        controller: function($scope, sharedProperties, $stateParams) {
          console.log($stateParams);
          messages = sharedProperties.getMessages();
          $scope.message = messsages.name[$stateParams.id];
    }
  })
```

Here is the messages array:

```
var messages = { 
  "Deputy": 
  {
    "name": "Deputy", 
    "message": ["Test", "Whey", "I See you!"]
  },
  "SOCO": 
  {
    "name": "SOCO",
    "message": ["Second Test", "Does this actually work?"]
  }
};
```

However when I go to `/#/messages/Deputy` I get redirected to **`/`** *(There's a redirect to say to go to `/` if page not found)*

Comment: do you have a parent states, like `app` and `messages`?

Comment: Anyway, you can [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745761/what-is-the-angular-ui-router-lifecycle-for-debugging-silent-errors/20786262#20786262) and try this to debug your routing. Hope it will help.

Comment: Could you try adding a / at the beginning of each url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be nice to see the complete picture of the state hierarchy. Because this:

> However when I go to `/#/messages/Deputy` I get redirected to **`/`** *(There's a redirect to say to go to **`/`** if page **not** found)*

could be related to parent state, which (I expect) already defines `/messages`

```
// parent
.state('app.messages', {
    url: '/messages',

// child should not repeat the parent's *url* part, it is already there
.state('app.messages.detail', {
    //url: 'messages/{id}',
    url: '/{id}',
```

Because without that adjustment (using doubled `/messages` definition) we would need url like this

```
/#/messages/messages/Deputy
```

Comment: This worked but how would they use different templates?

Answer (score 0):

when you run this code you should see an error like that at the console:

Cannot read property 'Deputy' of undefined

I think true message definition is should be:

```
$scope.message = messsages[$stateParams.id];
```