# angular-ui/ui-router $stateChangeError never fires for a state that does not exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My issue is that ui-router `$stateChangeError` is not triggered by a "404" invaild state.

I know for sure that my on `$stateChangeSucess` fires correctly:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)
```

When I intentionally make an invalid state like so:

```
 <ui-view>
    <a ui-sref="foo" style="cursor: pointer;">Foo is not a state</a>
 </ui-view>
```

The `$stateChangeError` event is not fired, I know I have the correct signature

```
angular
    .module('blocks.router')
    .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            console.log('$stateChangeError fired!');
        });
    }]);
```

And I add my function to `$stateChangeError` at the same time I add my working `$stateChangeSuccess`.

**Any suggestions to what I might be doing wrong?**

Comment: Do you implement `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()`? If so, that's why an invalid state won't trigger an error

Comment: No I am not currently implementing a $urlRouterProvider.otherwise()

Comment: @Phil adding  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/") did NOT trigger an error

Comment: I was mistaken. I thought that specifying an `otherwise` would mean you never had a state error from an unknown state but it appears that condition never happens anyway.

Comment: I have a similar problem, `$stateChangeError` does not fire for non-existing state, and while I have `.otherwise` implemented and `$stateChangeStart` is fired before navigating to it, unfortunately the parameters passed to it do not have the info of what was the original URL requested

Comment: It would be interesting to somehow be able to know what was the exact URL requested, for example, to handle deeplinks with hash for backward compatibility when changing the states names in the app etc.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745761/what-is-the-angular-ui-router-lifecycle-for-debugging-silent-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular-ui-router has [`$stateNotFound`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/ng1_state_events.html#_statenotfound) for such case

Answer (score 2):

So '$stateChangeError' will not fire for an invalid/misspelled state. For example if you state is "login" and you change state to "loginfoo" in a controller, '$stateChangeError' will not fire.

Now if your templateUrl location for state "login" is "app/templates/login.html" and you incorrectly name your template "app/templates/loginfoo.html" '$stateChangeError' will fire when you go to the "login" state.

So '$stateChangeError' fires for a valid state request that cannot find the controller, template, resource for that valid state. But it will not fire for a state that is misspelled aka simply does not exist.

Comment: Failed `resolve` promises will also trigger a state change error