# Ionic UI Router not working for child view

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a very simple lookbook application. Yet I can't seem to get the routes to work. I tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745761/what-is-the-angular-ui-router-lifecycle-for-debugging-silent-errors/20786262#20786262) to debug the routes. Nothing appeared in the console.

I'm trying to create an application where the user sees several looks on a page and can then navigate to the respective details page. It would be nice if Ionic also recognizes that the details page is a child page of the lookbook page. Thus showing the back button in the menu bar.

The `app.config` route setup code:

```
$stateProvider

  //Lookbook view
  .state('lookbook', {
    url: '/lookbook',
    views: {
      'main': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/lookbook.html',
        controller: function () {
          console.log('Lookbook controller loaded!');
        }
      }
    }
  })

  // Details view
  .state('lookbook.brand-shirt', {
    url: '/lookbook/brand-shirt',
    views: {
      'main': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/brand/shirt.html',
        controller: function () {
          console.log('Details controller loaded!');
        }
      }
    }
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/lookbook');
```

The `index.html` `<body>` contents:

```
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>

    <ion-nav-title>
      <img class="logo" alt="Lookbook Logo" ng-src="assets/images/icons/logo.svg">
    </ion-nav-title>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view name="main">
  </ion-nav-view>
```

The lookbook page shows up. But when I navigate to `/lookbook/brand-shirt` it reverts back to `/lookbook`. 
What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that routing, the `brand-shirt` state is a child of the lookbook state (`lookbook.brand-shirt`), as you don`t want to load the detail INSIDE the lookbook view, you don't need to make it like that.

```
 $stateProvider

  //Lookbook view
    .state('lookbook', {
    url: '/lookbook',
    views: {
      'main': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/lookbook.html',
        controller: function() {
          console.log('Lookbook controller loaded!');
        }
      }
    }
  })

  // Details view
  .state('brand-shirt', {
    url: '/lookbook/brand-shirt',
    views: {
      'main': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/brand/shirt.html',
        controller: function() {
          console.log('Details controller loaded!');
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/lookbook');
```

Do it like that. And the history will work the same because you are pushing views in your `'main'` `ion-nav-view`. So at the start of your app `/lookbook` is loaded in `main`, when you go to `brand-shirt`, that new view goes above in the `main` views stack. If you go back, you will be removing the details view and going back to the `lookbook`.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/tinchomm/pen/Lxygao)

Comment: Your solution works, but without child states I cannot reuse parent's resolved parameters via ui-router resolve

Comment: You can send the object to the child state as a parameter or use a service to handle the saving and getting of the object.